# Are Unity VectorN variables recalculated?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Unity allows access to vector.magnitude/sqrMagnitude/normalized values through a read only *variable* and I am unsure if its a c# feature or a unity thing. However I would like to know if I use it multiple times without changing the vector will it recompute the value or return it from the previous computation.

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.html

Comment: it's better to ask unity support

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to reliably answer this question, one has to look into the bytecode that is executed. In other words, we just open up the `UnityEngine.dll` in Telerik's decompiler to see what's going on in that class. In my case that file was located at `C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\Managed\UnityEngine.dll`.

Here we can see the (partial) contents of the `UnityEngine.Vector3` class:

[image]
[image]

You wanted to know about `Vector3.magnitude`, `Vector3.sqrMagnitude` and `Vector3.normalized`. The code for `.magnitude` is:

```
    public float magnitude
    {
        get
        {
            return Mathf.Sqrt(this.x * this.x + this.y * this.y + this.z * this.z);
        }
    }
```

This is a straighforward implementation of a read-only property that computates the magnitude of the vector. As you can see, no caching is done. Let's see `sqrMagnitude`.

```
    public float sqrMagnitude
    {
        get
        {
            return this.x * this.x + this.y * this.y + this.z * this.z;
        }
    }
```

Nope, the same here, no caching involved. However, `.normalized` is interesting.

```
    public Vector3 normalized
    {
        get
        {
            return Vector3.Normalize(this);
        }
    }
```

Which leads us to:

```
    public static Vector3 Normalize(Vector3 value)
    {
        float single = Vector3.Magnitude(value);
        if (single <= 1E-05f)
        {
            return Vector3.zero;
        }
        return value / single;
    }
```

The static method `Vector3.magnitude` is the same as the member-function implementation but with an explicit `Vector3` input parameter ofcourse.

So, as you can see from the decompiled bytecode: No caching is done when computing `.sqrtMagnitude`, `.magnitude` or `.normalized`. So, it is in turn wise to only compute these values once and then reuse them if possible, for performance gain.